# CodeIgniter Form is not Submitting

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to php and I'm trying to develop a simple project using CodeIgniter php framework. I'm following the tutorial in CodeIgniter website.

My problem is I have create a model,view and controller as the tutorial. But my `create` form is not submitted when I click the submit button. other functions are working correctly.

I followed below tutorial:
[Tutorial](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/create_news_items.html)

Thanks in advance.

View

```
<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('news/create'); ?>
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="input" name="title" /><br />
    <label for="text">Text</label>
    <textarea name="text"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create news item" />
</form>
```

Model

```
<?php

class News_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_news($slug = FALSE) {
        if ($slug === FALSE) {
            $query = $this->db->get('news');
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }

    public function set_news() {

        $this->load->helper('url');

        $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

        $data = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'slug' => $slug,
            'text' => $this->input->post('text')
        );

        return $this->db->insert('news', $data);
    }

}
```

Controller

```
<?php

class News extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('news_model');
        $this->load->helper('url_helper');
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();

        $data['title'] = 'Title passes from conttoller';

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function view($slug = NULL) {
        $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);

        if (empty($data['news_item'])) {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function create() {

        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $data['title'] = 'Create a news item';

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'Text', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('news/create');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        } else {
            $this->news_model->set_news();
            $this->load->view('news/success');
        }
    }

}
```

Routes:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

Comment: use echo form_close().https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=form

Comment: @HarshitSethi But I followed the tutorial in CodeIgniter official website. (Question updated) Can you please tell me mistake I have made..?
[web link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/create_news_items.html)

Comment: do you created the route $route['news/create'] = 'news/create'; ?

Comment: Yes. I added my routes.php code into the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new with Codeigniter, please dont play with "config/routes.php"

`create` form is not submitted when clicked the submit button? HTML form should submitted the form by default (browser will refresh)

Please check in the "Inspect Element > Network" at your browser before you click the form, and see what is going on